# Как правильно сделать редирект через .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Как правильно сделать редирект через .htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?go=profile&id=$1
RewriteRule ^audio([0-9]+)$ page.php?go=audio&id=$1
```

Как сделать такой страницы `site.ru/abc` и `site.ru/audio123`

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['go']) == 'profile') {
    echo 'Profile';
} else if (isset($_GET['go']) == 'audio') {
    echo 'Audio';
}
?>
```

Получаю только `Profile`. А как получить Profile или Audio?

Comment: RewriteRule поменяйте местами: более узкое по охвату правило ставьте на первое место.

Comment: @Visman спасибо за совет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом правиле проверить наличие `audio`

```
RewriteRule ^(?!audio)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?go=profile&id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?go=profile&id=$1
```

либо поменять местами условия

```
RewriteRule ^audio([0-9]+)$ page.php?go=audio&id=$1
RewriteRule ^video([0-9]+)$ page.php?go=video&id=$1
RewriteRule ^photo([0-9]+)$ page.php?go=photo&id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?go=profile&id=$1
```

Comment: Спасибо а как добавить еще video и photo и т.д. ?

Comment: @KYRAN дополнил ответ